# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC C# Seeding many to many relationships using seeder not onModelCreating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a many to many relationship between contacts and categories. LINQ has created  the SQL junction table `CategoryContact`. I have tried several different things to try to assign categories to contacts but haven't had any success. Most of the info online is how to do this with the `OnModelCreating` method, but I haven't found anything on how to do this in a seeder class.

Here are a few samples of things I tried...

```
await _dbContext.Categories.Add(contactId).ToString();

category.Add(contact);


foreach (int categoryId in CategoryList)
{
    await _addressBookService.AddContactToCategoryAsync(categoryId, contact.Id);
}
```

All of the above didn't work for reasons I was unable to successfully debug.

Basically I want to assign one of the categories to each contact so the contacts are seeded with a category attached/assigned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code.

Seeder class

```
using ContactPro.Data;
using ContactPro.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace ContactPro.Helpers
{
    public class DataSeeder
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

        private string? appUserId;

        List<Contact> contact = new List<Contact>();
        List<Category> category = new List<Category>();

        public DataSeeder(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task SeedDataAsync()
        {
            await SeedUsersAsync();
            await SeedContactsAsync();
            await SeedCategoriesAsync();
        }

        private async Task SeedUsersAsync()
        {
            if (!_dbContext.Users.Any())
            {
                var demoUser = new AppUser()
                {
                    UserName = "demouser@mail.com",
                    Email = "demouser@mail.com",
                    FirstName = "Demo",
                    LastName = "User",
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };

                await _userManager.CreateAsync(demoUser, "xxxxxx");
            }

            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            appUserId = (await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("demouser@mail.com")).Id;
        }

        private async Task SeedContactsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_dbContext.Contacts.Any())
                {
                    contact = new List<Contact>()
                    {
                        new Contact()
                        {
                            FirstName = "John",
                            LastName = "Dickens",
                            Address1 = "12 Main St.",
                            City = "Concord",
                            States  = ContactPro.Enums.States.NH,
                            ZipCode = 03101,
                            Email = "john@mail.com",
                            BirthDate = new DateTime(1994,8,20),
                            PhoneNumber = "(212)345-8587",
                            DateCreated = new DateTime(2023,5,20),
                            AppUserId = appUserId,
                        }
                    };
                }

                await _dbContext.Contacts.AddRangeAsync(contact);
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*************  ERROR  *************");
                Console.WriteLine("Error Seeding Contacts.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("***********************************");
                throw;
            }
        }

        private async Task SeedCategoriesAsync()
        {
            if (!_dbContext.Categories.Any())
            {
                category = new List<Category>()
                {
                    new Category()
                    {
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                        Name = "_UnCategorized",
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Friend",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Colleague",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Vendor",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Contractor",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Send Invitation",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    }
                };
            }
            await _dbContext.Categories.AddRangeAsync(category);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Contact model (only included relevant properties)

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? AppUserId { get; set; }

    // virtual
    public virtual AppUser? AppUser { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new HashSet<Category>();
}
```

Category model

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? AppUserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public virtual AppUser? AppUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new HashSet<Contact>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update2:**

If you have multiple `Contact`, you need to specify `Category` separately. Please refer to the code below:

```
public class DataSeeder
{
    public static async Task InitializeAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = new ApplicationDbContext(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>());

        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();

        string? appUserId;
        List<Contact> contact = new List<Contact>();
        List<Category> category = new List<Category>();

        using (context)
        {
            if (!context.Users.Any())
            {
                var demoUser = new AppUser()
                {
                    UserName = "demouser@mail.com",
                    Email = "demouser@mail.com",
                    FirstName = "Demo",
                    LastName = "User",
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };

                await userManager.CreateAsync(demoUser, "Aa12345!");
            }
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            appUserId = (await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("demouser@mail.com")).Id;

            try
            {
                if (!context.Contacts.Any())
                {
                    contact = new List<Contact>()
                    {
                        new Contact()
                        {
                            FirstName = "John",
                            LastName = "Dickens",
                            City = "Concord",
                            Email = "john@mail.com",
                            BirthDate = new DateTime(1994,8,20),
                            PhoneNumber = "(212)345-8587",
                            DateCreated = new DateTime(2023,5,20),
                            AppUserId = appUserId,
                        },
                        new Contact()
                        {
                            FirstName = "Tom",
                            LastName = "Smith",
                            City = "Concord",
                            Email = "tom@mail.com",
                            BirthDate = new DateTime(1994,8,20),
                            PhoneNumber = "(212)345-8587",
                            DateCreated = new DateTime(2023,5,20),
                            AppUserId = appUserId,
                        }
                    };
                    await context.Contacts.AddRangeAsync(contact);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*************  ERROR  ************");
                Console.WriteLine("Error Seeding Contacts.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("***********************************");
                throw;
            }

           if (!context.Categories.Any())
           {
                category = new List<Category>()
                {
                    new Category()
                    {
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                        Name = "_UnCategorized"
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Friend",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Colleague",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Vendor",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Contractor",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Send Invitation",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    }
                };
            }
            contact[0].Categories = new List<Category>();
            contact[0].Categories.Add(category.Find(c => c.Name == "Contractor"));
            contact[1].Categories = new List<Category>();
            contact[1].Categories.Add(category.Find(c => c.Name == "Vendor"));

            context.Contacts.Update(contact[0]);
            context.Contacts.Update(contact[1]);
            await context.Categories.AddRangeAsync(category);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }     
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

---

**Update:**

You mean that the `CategoryContact` table is generated after migrating to the database, which contains `ContactId` and `CategoryId` as the primary key, but it is not filled with data, right?

This is because you didn't populate the `Categories` property in `Contact` and the `Contacts` property in `Category`.

Take my code as an example，I added a `new Contact()` to operate on the `Categories` property and update the database at the end:

```
public class DataSeeder
{
    public static async Task InitializeAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = new ApplicationDbContext(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>());

        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();

        string? appUserId;

        //Add this line
        var contactItem = new Contact();


        List<Contact> contact = new List<Contact>();
        List<Category> category = new List<Category>();

        using (context)
        {
            if (!context.Users.Any())
            {
                var demoUser = new AppUser()
                {
                    UserName = "demouser@mail.com",
                    Email = "demouser@mail.com",
                    FirstName = "Demo",
                    LastName = "User",
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };
                await userManager.CreateAsync(demoUser, "Aa12345!");
            }
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            appUserId = (await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("demouser@mail.com")).Id;

            try
            {
                if (!context.Contacts.Any())
                {
                    contactItem = new Contact()
                    {
                        FirstName = "John",
                        LastName = "Dickens",
                        City = "Concord",
                        Email = "john@mail.com",
                        BirthDate = new DateTime(1994, 8, 20),
                        PhoneNumber = "(212)345-8587",
                        DateCreated = new DateTime(2023, 5, 20),
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*************  ERROR  *************");
                Console.WriteLine("Error Seeding Contacts.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("***********************************");
                throw;
            }

            if (!context.Categories.Any())
            {
                category = new List<Category>()
                {
                    new Category()
                    {
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                        Name = "_UnCategorized",
                        Contacts = contact
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Friend",
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                        Contacts = contact
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Colleague",
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                        Contacts = contact
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Vendor",
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                        Contacts = contact
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Contractor",
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                        Contacts = contact
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Send Invitation",
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                        Contacts = contact
                    }
                };
            }

            //Operate the database at the end
            contactItem.Categories = category;
            contact.Add(contactItem);
            await context.Contacts.AddRangeAsync(contact);
            await context.Categories.AddRangeAsync(category);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }     
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

---

Is your `DataSeeder` running successfully? I modified your code according to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#seed-the-database) and it works.

DataSeeder.cs:

```
public class DataSeeder
{
    public static async Task InitializeAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = new ApplicationDbContext(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>());

        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();

        string? appUserId;
        List<Contact> contact = new List<Contact>();
        List<Category> category = new List<Category>();

        using (context)
        {
            if (!context.Users.Any())
            {
                var demoUser = new AppUser()
                {
                    UserName = "demouser@mail.com",
                    Email = "demouser@mail.com",
                    FirstName = "Demo",
                    LastName = "User",
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };

                await userManager.CreateAsync(demoUser, "Aa12345!");
            }
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            appUserId = (await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("demouser@mail.com")).Id;

            try
            {
                if (!context.Contacts.Any())
                {
                    contact = new List<Contact>()
                    {
                        new Contact()
                        {
                            FirstName = "John",
                            LastName = "Dickens",
                            City = "Concord",
                            Email = "john@mail.com",
                            BirthDate = new DateTime(1994,8,20),
                            PhoneNumber = "(212)345-8587",
                            DateCreated = new DateTime(2023,5,20),
                            AppUserId = appUserId,
                        }
                    };
                }

                await context.Contacts.AddRangeAsync(contact);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*************  ERROR  *************");
                Console.WriteLine("Error Seeding Contacts.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("***********************************");
                throw;
            }

            if (!context.Categories.Any())
            {
                category = new List<Category>()
                {
                    new Category()
                    {
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                        Name = "_UnCategorized",
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Friend",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Colleague",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Vendor",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Contractor",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    },
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "Send Invitation",
                        AppUserId = appUserId
                    }
                };
            }
            await context.Categories.AddRangeAsync(category);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }     
}
```

Program.cs:

```
var app = builder.Build();
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    await DataSeeder.InitializeAsync(services);
}
```

After [migrating and updating the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#initial-migration), run the project, the data is successfully added to the database.

Comment: Thank you Chen for the updated code. Yes the seeder I posted works. What I would like to do is assign categories to the contacts in the seeder, which is many to many. You can see my original post for more details. I will update it.

Comment: Hi @David, I updated my answer. Please check if this is what you want.

Comment: Yes that is great! Almost there. I want to specify which contact gets which category.
 I intend to add more contacts to the seeder, and want to assign different categories to different contacts;
 So for example the first contact will get the ```Vendor``` category and the second contact will get the ```Contractor``` category.
 I've tried using indexes ```=category[0]``` and find methods ```=category.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Name == "Vendor");``` but no luck so far.

Comment: I have added a second contact but when I ran the application it did not seed the second contact so I moved
 ```contact.Add(contactItem);``` and placed it under each contactItem and it added the second contact
 but didn't assign any categories to it.

Comment: Hi @David, Please check my second updated answer.